# SQL query SP to get data from 11 tables and avoid Cartesian output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 11 different tables with same PK column, am trying to create a table (like de-normalized version of the 11 tables) 
Some of the tables have 4 rows for same PK column, some have 6.
If I use join for all 11 tables, final output seems like an Cartesian product.

Is there any better way to achieve the result, am OK to create a SP for this, but need some guidance for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Ko

Comment: Do the tables all share the same columns (doubt it, but worth asking)?  Also, do you have a table which has a master list of all PK values which appear in the 11 tables?

Comment: Hi Tim, they have different columns.
yes, I have a table which has all the PK values in it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a single table containing all PK values, then you may start with that table and then left join to the other 11 tables, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table mt
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON mt.PK = t1.PK
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON mt.PK = t2.PK
...
LEFT JOIN table11 t11
    ON mt.PK = t11.PK;
```

The net result of this is that only records corresponding to the original set of primary key values would appear in your result set.  `NULL` values would either indicate that a given table did not match, or it did match, but happened to record a `NULL` for a certain column.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the suggestion, I will try this option and let you know how it goes

Comment: The important thing here is that you always join from the master table, _not_ the other tables.  In other words, don't chain the joins, that could lead to duplicated records.

Comment: Hi Tim, I faced the same issue, table 1 had 1 row, table 2 --> 4 rows, table 3 --> 2 rows, so far now, the output was 8 rows.. after I joined the table 4 --> 4 rows, the output was 32 rows, after joining table 5  which has 8 rows, the output was 448 rows. 
:(

Comment: If you used my actually query this could not have happened.  The master table has N PK rows.  Therefore the output must also have N rows.  Rows can never be duplicated, because each PK column in all 11 tables contains, by definition, only unique values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible if all 11 tables are using the same column to join. Unfortunately, for this case, you would end up with Cartesian result due to M-M relationship between the tables.

For example:

Provided you have 3 tables that store User/UserPhone/UserAddress

1-User can have N-PhoneNumbers and 1-User can have N-Addresses.

So if you join them all using UserID, the end result would be 1-UserID * N-PhoneNumber * N-Addresses.

Comment: Yes, thats what is happening...Is there any way we could avoid that?